# Auto-generate isCrossRef in schema.xml

Tags: propel

I'm currently developing a modular site with silex, propel and twig.
It is my intention to create an installer project on top of it so I can easily create new projects based on my "core" project.

My database has some many-to-many table which require the [isCrossRef](http://propelorm.org/documentation/04-relationships.html) attribute in my schema.xml. When reverse engineering my MySql database Propel can't determine which tables are crossRef. I get that, but now I was wondering if I could alter the schema.xml generation.

Lets says If I add a comment to the tables that need this isCrossRef attribute, then where in the Propel source code would I be able to read out this comment and add the required IsCrossRef to the generated schema.xml ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading some of the source code I found the answer myself :

If u want to accomplish this u will need the modify the file : MysqlSchemaParser.php, located at : propel1/generator/lib/reverse/mysql (when installed with composer)

Alter the recordset at line 99 to :

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
    $name = $row[0];
    $type = $row[1];

    if ($name == $this->getMigrationTable() || $type != "BASE TABLE") {
        continue;
    }
    /*
        Edit : Find out if table isCrossRef 
    */
    $commentStmt = $this->dbh->query("show table status like '".$name."'");
    $commentRow  = $commentStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $isCrossRef = (strtolower($commentRow->Comment) == 'iscrossref');
    /*
        End of edit
    */

    if ($task) {
        $task->log("  Adding table '" . $name . "'", Project::MSG_VERBOSE);
    }

    $table = new Table($name);
    $table->setIdMethod($database->getDefaultIdMethod());
    $table->setIsCrossRef($isCrossRef); /*EDIT : set is crossref to true*/
    $database->addTable($table);
    $tables[] = $table;
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to actually have this feature in Propel itself so editing the core code isn't required. It's a pain to manually edit the schema again and again if you have a lot of crossreference tables.

Comment: In propel 2.X it''s much easier and cleaner to implement this because u can create your own tasks for the generator. Other than that i'm still using this code to auto generate my models and schema through my cms

Comment: Do you have a link for me where I can read up on creating own tasks for the generator?

Comment: Documentation on that topic is scarce. I will look If I can find my code for the propel 2.x version